# UnsatisfiedLinkError using JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am currently trying to use JNI to use some native code to get the console width and height, but i keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: project.console.NativeConsole.getConsoleWidth()I
at project.console.NativeConsole.getConsoleWidth(Native Method)
at project.Core.main(Core.java:14)
```

i've searched over the web what this exception is and how to fix it, but with no success

this is my current code:

Main.java

```
package project;

import project.console.NativeConsole;

public class Core {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NativeConsole console = new NativeConsole();
        console.getConsoleWidth();
    }

}
```

NativeConsole.java

```
package project.console;

public class NativeConsole {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("NativeConsole");
    }

    public native int getConsoleWidth();
    public native int getConsoleHeight();
    public native void clearConsole();

}
```

the dll is written in c++ and is a .cpp and a .h file compiled into a .dll file

cpp file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "project_console_NativeConsole.h"

/*
 * Class:     project_console_NativeConsole
 * Method:    getConsoleWidth
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL     Java_project_console_NativeConsole_getConsoleWidth(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO inf;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &inf);
    return (jint) inf.dwSize.X;
}

/*
 * Class:     project_console_NativeConsole
 * Method:    getConsoleHeight
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL     Java_project_console_NativeConsole_getConsoleHeight(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO inf;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &inf);
    return (jint) inf.srWindow.Bottom - inf.srWindow.Top;
}

/*
 * Class:     project_console_NativeConsole
 * Method:    clearConsole
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_project_console_NativeConsole_clearConsole(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    system("cls");
    return;
}
```

i dont know if i can include more information now, but my current question is, why am i getting this exception? because i think its a little vague.

Comment: Looks like it can't find the DLL.

Comment: nope, its the method call that creates the error, if it couldnt find the library it would have given this error
https://pastebin.com/ratDBWA9

Comment: In addition to Tripp's comment, it's possible that you don't have the right file permissions on your dll file

Comment: I'm testing your code and it works. What command do you use to compile?

Comment: i am using `g++ -shared -o NativeConsole.dll -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\include\win32" .\project_console_NativeConsole.cpp .\project_console_NativeConsole.h` to compile the files

Comment: @Human hmm works fine for me too... And you haven't touched the header file at all?

Comment: nope, i havent, unless placing it in another directory means it breaks it, but i dont think so

Comment: @Human You could check if the created DLL really exports the three native methods and that it is really a 32bit dll.

Comment: how would i check that exactly?

Comment: You can check with the Microsoft tool `depends` (with newish, easy-to-get version at http://www.dependencywalker.com). Pick the 32-bit or 64-bit build that you need. Try the Profile feature, too, with your java.exe command.

Comment: Is this 64-bit Cygwin? I seem to remember other questions where JNI with 64-bit Cygwin didn't work.

Comment: nope, im using mingw64, i686-7.3.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v5-rev0

Comment: It's the same for mingw64. I found some posts advising to use the `--kill-at` linker option. Maybe you could try that.